# Is there a way to search for upcoming Dividends by type?

Tags: stock-markets, dividends, capital-gain

I was searching for dividends and can see the calendar for most of symbols.
However, I bumped into `$KWEB` and they declared on Dec-28-2021 and Ex-Div date was Dec-29-2021 and Pay Date was Dec-31-2021.

However, I did not see this symbol on Fidelity, NASDAQ, or TDAmeritrade calendars. Why?

When, searching for `$KWEB` on Fidelity I see the following screen as below. And I noticed (also learned, I guess?) that there are different types of Distributions; Dividends and Long Term Capital Gain.

Question is, is there a screen, or calendar, that shows a Distribution calendar for upcoming events and filter them by type?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

KWEB declared a special dividend of $2.58 on 12/29/21.

A special dividend is one that is not regularly scheduled so therefore you cannot screen or search for it. At best, if a company has a pattern of declaring special dividends, you might be able to anticipate the date but definitely not the amount.

And while you did not ask this, there is no benefit to receiving a dividend other than cash flow that lowers your cash at risk.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Is there a way to search for special dividends across the market? My thoughts are to finding an options trading strategy as the price can move sharply on those days, no?

Comment: As stated, special dividends are not regularly scheduled dividends.  Known dividends are priced into options so there would be no advantage in knowing such information.  In addition, special dividends result in adjustment to the options.  Look up an option chain for KWEB.  You're going to find options with strike prices ending in 42 or 92 cents.  That's because the options were adjusted for the dividend (a call with a strike price of $50 before the special dividend now has a strike price of $47.42).    Does your head hurt yet?  :->)

Comment: I just thought about how the heads of the guys doing those options adjustments must hurt... and they better not miss a beat ever, or someone loses money...

Comment: Adjusted options are a royal PITA and as you noted, easy to make a mistake with.  In addition, their bid/ask spread tends to widen because of declining liquidity so you pay the piper to get out.  I avoid them whenever possible.  If a corporate event is announced, I get out of Dodge if I can.  If it's unexpected, I set up a spreadsheet to prevent missing that beat and possible beating.

Comment: @BobBaerker thank you for clarifying the price. I was wondering why it was priced so.